# working with different workbooks within the same code

Tags: excel, vba

When referring to different workbooks within a code I have been using "Set Workbooks.Open".

Example:

```
`Dim wbname1 as Workbook
Dim wbname2 as Workbook


'code which refers to wbname1
Set wbname1 = Workbooks.Open("path\filename")

'code which refers to wbname2
Set wbname2 = Workbooks.Open("path\filename")`
```

This is sometimes inconvenient because in order to refer again to a previous workbook, I would have to close the workbook and reopen it.

Example:

```
` 'code which refers to wbname1
Set wbname1 = Workbooks.Open("path\filename")
wbname1.Close True

'code which refers to wbname2
Set wbname2 = Workbooks.Open("path\filename")

'code which refers again to wbname1
Set wbname1 = Workbooks.Open("path\filename")`
```

I have had to work around this problem especially when using different workbooks within a loop.

Is there an easier way to refer to different workbooks than using

`Set Workbooks.Open()`

Comment: you only have to `Workbooks.Open` when the workbook is closed. If it's already open, you can write `Set wbname1 = Workbooks("myWB.xlsx")` That said, once you open it, it will always be set the variable name you give it and there's no need to close and re-open it. Just close it when you are done processing it.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. If you're operating on a Workbook, then just close it when you're done with it. If you need more than one Workbook open at any one time, just track that with an array or something. But just close them after you've finished with them. Keep it open until you're done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Dim book1 as Workbook
> ```

You're declaring a variable here, of type `Workbook`. When you use the `Set` keyword, you're *assigning* the variable a *reference*.

> ```
> Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("path\filename1")`
> ```

Here the reference is returned as a *result* of calling `Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open`, a function in the Excel object model that, well, opens a workbook and returns a *reference* to the workbook it opened, if the operation was successful.

> *This is sometimes inconvenient because in order to refer again to a previous workbook, I would have to close the workbook and reopen it.*

Not at all. **You already hold a reference to two workbooks**, all you need to do is, well, *use them*!

```
Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("path\filename1")
Set book2 = Workbooks.Open("path\filename2")

'work with book1
book1.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "Hello"

'work with book2
book2.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "World!"

'all done, clean up now:
book1.Close
book2.Close
```